# expression must be a modifiable lvalue in my class

Tags: c++, lvalue

I know what it means but in my situation I don't understand why my IDE yelling me about this.

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& that1, const Rational& that2)
{
    Rational temp(that1);
    temp.getNom() *= that2.getNom();
    temp.getDenom() *= that2.getDenom();
    return temp;
}

int Rational::getNom() const
{
    return m_iNom / gcd(m_iNom, m_iDenom);
}
int Rational::getDenom() const
{
    return m_iDenom / gcd(m_iNom, m_iDenom);
}

float Rational::gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

m_iNom & m_iDenom are private data members inside Rational class.

I'm getting 'expression must be a modifiable lvalue' at :

```
temp.getNom() *= that2.getNom();
temp.getDenom() *= that2.getDenom();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot affect a value to a function or method return.

`temp.getNom() *= that2.getNom();` is like `temp.getNom() = temp.getNom() * that2.getNom();`

It's like to write `2 = 2 * 3` and set `2 = 5` … no sense!

Comment: what would I do if I want to return the nom and denom and change it via a function call like what I did here then, would I have to make setters?

Comment: Call a setter (`.setNom` ?) or access directly to the field if you are allowed.

Comment: hoped I could do that without setters, but ok thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, you can't assign to the return value.
Even if you could assign to the return value, the member variables would be unaffected —
the accessors return the values of the member variables, not the actual variables.

The idiomatic way of doing this is to first implement `operator *=` as a member:

```
Rational& operator *= (const Rational& that)
{
    m_iNom *= that.m_iNom;
    m_iDenom *= that.m_iDenom;
    return *this;
}
```

and then use that to implement `*`:

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& that1, const Rational& that2)
{
    Rational result(that1);
    result *= that2;
    return result;
}
```